# Date format in a function WordPress ACF

Tags: date, format

I have asked a similar question in the past but still have issues...
I am therefore placing the whole function here.

Can anyone tell me how to change the format that the date is output?
Currently it shows 20130731
I want it to show 31st July 2013

```
function le_detail() {

?>
<div class="event">
    <!--Standard WP - use 'echo' -->
    <h2 class="button"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
    <!-- ACF - NO 'echo' -->
    <h3><?php the_field('where'); ?></h3>
    <h3><?php the_field('when'); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
    <p>Chairman: <?php the_field('chairman'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php       


}
```

The date is the line: (this is using the Advanced Customs Fields plugin)

```
<h3><?php the_field('when'); ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF plugin is having get_field('') function to get the value of the custom field. Since you have used 'when' as the field name, so do as follows:

```
<h3><?php echo date("dS F,Y",strtotime(get_field('when'))); ?></h3>
```

Use the above code snippet, that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had this same problem until I tried it this way:

```
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('my_datefield')); 
    //use your field name
```

then...

```
<li>Ticket Date: <?php echo $date->format('d M, Y'); ?> </li>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Great, how to translate into my language now?